# Why is this javascript for loop running only once?

Tags: javascript, for-loop, var

```
function f1() {
   for (i = 0; i <= 5; i++)
      console.log(i);
}
function foo() {
   for (i = 0; i < 5; i++)
      f1();
}
foo();
```

Hi, I'm trying to understand why the result of executing foo is:

```
0
1
2
3
4
5
```

And not:

```
0
1
2
3
4
5
0
1
2
3
4
5
0
1
2
3
4
5
0
1
2
3
4
5
0
1
2
3
4
5
```

It's a slide I am reading about JS and its talking about when you don't use var then it is defined on the global object and provides this example without any further details why we get the result.

I thought it will simply loop and run the f1 function each time until its less than 5.

Please help me understand.

Thanks

Comment: `i` is global and *shared* between your functions. Use `var` to make both instances local.

Comment: Thanks for all your responses. I already tested with var and got the result I was expecting. I wanted to understand why it was doing that.

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong. So basically, because the script encounters the i in f1, it runs this and doesn't bother running the i in foo???

Comment: @Kam: I've added a short description of what's happening to my answer.

Comment: The fact is that, as written, `i` is a shared global variable, so `foo` starts, sets is to `0` then calls `f1` which loop on it up to `5`, when control returns to `foo` it founds that `i` is `5` and so it ends the loop.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The problem is in your iterators (`i`):

```
for (i = 0; i <= 5; i++)
```

`i` is global, and both your `for` loops test against it, making them only run once, and aborting when `i == 5`.

So, what happens is this:

When you call `foo()`, `foo` tells the js interpreter to create a variable in the global scope called `i`, and set it to `0`. Then `foo` calls `f1`.
There, the `for` loop sets `i`, which already exists, to `0`, and runs it's loop like it should, incrementing `i` up to `5`.
Then, it's time for the second iteration of the loop in `foo`, so it checks if `i < 5`, but it's not (`i==6` (`5` from `f1`, `+1` from `foo`)), so it will not call `f1` again.

To fix this, either declare them in the function's local scope using `var`:

```
function f1() {
    for (var i = 0; i <= 5; i++)
        console.log(i);
}
function foo() {
    for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        f1();
}
foo();
```

Or, use different variables:

```
function f1() {
    for (i = 0; i <= 5; i++)
        console.log(i);
}
function foo() {
    for (j = 0; j < 5; j++)
        f1();
}
foo();
```

However, this second option is a bad idea, since it will both place `i` and `j` in the global scope, which is asking for conflicts. I'd suggest using the `var` option.

Comment: @Downvoter: I edited in a bit of information explaining why option 2 isn't a good idea. I'd appreciate if the downvote could be removed.

Comment: Good answer but I can't approve the second solution. Using global variables like this will inevitably cause problems and become a pain to debug.

Comment: @sebcap26: And that's exactly why I said that the second option is a bad idea, right below that option.

Comment: Actually, after `f1` has executed, it should be `i == 6`

Answer (score 9):

If you write your loop like

```
for (i = 0; i < 5; i++)
```

here `i` refers to a global variable, because you have not declared it with the `var` keyword, and since you use `i` in both functions, they end up actually using the same variable.

You should then replace both loops with

```
function f1() {
   for (var i = 0; i <= 5; i++)
      console.log(i);
}
function foo() {
   for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++)
      f1();
}
foo();
```

As your code is originally written, `i` is a shared global variable, so `foo` starts, sets is to `0` then calls f1 which loop on it up to `6`, when control returns to `foo` it founds that `i` is `6`, so `i < 5` is `false` and so it ends the loop.

Comment: this is a precise and direct answer to the question